# How can I save a log file with nohup command?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, nohup

I am trying to run a python script in the background in a Raspbian OS. When I use the following command:

```
nohup python <script> >> log.txt
```

where `<script>` is the python file name. The program saves all the outputs in the log.txt, but it only saves them when I terminate the program, as it is a never-ending loop (I know this because I opened another terminal and used `tail -f log.txt`). Moreover, if I use the following command:

```
nohup python <script> >> log.txt &
```

The file log.txt is created but the data does not append.
Any suggestions on why is that happening? Thank you in advance!

PS: I tried using sudo in the command in order to know if the error was the permissions, but the result was the same. I also tried `&>>`, same result.

Comment: Probably python output buffering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

Many tools (and python too) use output buffering for optimization: Output is stored until a amount of data is collected (usually multiple of 4KB). And then exact this block is output. python supports option -u.

Maybe you have to save stderr too (`2>&1` behind redirection).

So my solution is:

```
nohup python -u <script> >> log.txt 2>&1 &
#            ^^                     ^^^^
```